# Decode specific part of JSON response using a model conforming to the Codable protocol

Tags: json, swift, codable, jsondecoder

Suppose I have an API that consists of this sample response with a structure like this:

[image: JSON response]

I create a model like this:

```
struct Post: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var body: String
    var userId: Int
}
```

When I try to decode this using:

```
let decodedPosts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data)
```

This fails as the response structure does not match model's structure as the `Posts` array is nested inside the JSON object.

I usually have this situation as the data I actually need is nested within the JSON response.

To solve the above situation, I parse the JSON data the old way without relying on `Codable`, retrieve the object I want, convert that object into data and then carry on with decoding it using `Codable` as follows:

```
do {
    let responseJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any], let posts = responseJSON["posts"] {
        let postData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: posts,
                                              options: .prettyPrinted)
        
        let decodedPosts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: postData)
        completion(.success(decodedPosts))
    }
}
catch {
    completion(.failure(.decodeError))
}
```

While this works, I feel that I am doing the the round-about / incorrect way.

I did think create another overarching generic Model which consists of the nested types as properties, however, I still didn't feel this was appropriate for example:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var posts: [Post]
}
```

Is there any advice on how to retrieve data that is nested using `Codadble` without manually having to parse the JSON first or is there a better way in general ?

Comment: Your JSON is not an array of `Post`: it is an object that contains a property "posts" of type array of `Post`.

Comment: let decodedPosts = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: postData) use this code...

Comment: Why didn't you feel having the `Response` struct was appropriate?

Comment: Your Response struct is perfectly valid.

Comment: You could decode it as [String: [Post]] if you don’t want to create the top level struct. And you shouldn’t ignore any errors thrown by the decoder so declare `decodeError` to have an associated type of type `Error`.

Comment: @Sweeper - perhaps I was overthinking ... I felt since I didn't have any specific use of Response besides just using it for decoding purposes, I assumed there was a better way .. thanks for your advice

Comment: @RobC - thanks for this advice. I initially thought the only purpose of `Response` was for decoding and perhaps there was another way than creating a struct just for decoding.

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson - that is actually something I didn't think of and I think it would solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not an array of `Post`: it is an object that contains a property "posts" of type array of `Post`.

So, you first need to implement this object:

```
struct JSONPosts {
    var posts: [Post]
}
```

Then, you can decode:

```
let decodedContainer = try JSONDecoder().decode(JSONPosts.self, from: data)

let decodedPosts = decodedContainer.posts
```